# Rails checkbox value is always nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm fairly new to Rails, and am having trouble getting the value of a check box. I've spent quite a few hours looking through threads and API documentation but still can't seem to get any value other than nil out of it.

The check box is not bound to a property of any model, but is intended to be a boolean that will filter out / in ignored elements

Here's the check box declaration:

```
<%= form_tag model_path, :method => 'get', :id => "data_search" do %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :direction, params[:direction] %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :sort, params[:sort] %>
    <p>
       <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
       <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
       <%= hidden_field_tag "include_ignored", 0 %> //tried the hidden field trick also, to
                                                    //no avail
       <%= check_box_tag "include_ignored", 0 %>
       Include ignored items
    </p>
<% end %>
```

Note that I've tried declaring the check box tag outside the form_for as well to no effect

Later I'm using this in a model search:

```
Model.where(:is_ignored => params[:include_ignored])
```

The query output in the console tells the same story as the debugger; params[:include_ignored] is null.

What could I be missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay if you are saying that when you click submit
then the check box state is not passed along (always is 0)
then it's because of your final agrugment on the tag.

Should be

```
<%= check_box_tag "include_ignored" %>
```

don't put the 0 after it.

Comment: That's part of it, but it also doesn't appear to have a default value to begin with. When the page loads for the first time, my goal is that the value of this checkbox should be false so the table should only display un-ignored items. I could handle this case in the controller easily enough but that won't help me if I can't get a new value to overwrite with later...

Comment: Um I don't understand here.  Yes the check_box_tag will default to unchecked as that is what the html shows when the page is rendered.  Are you saying then on later calls you want to control from the controller if the check box is clicked or not?

Comment: I'm trying to use the value of the checkbox as a boolean and use that to determine whether or not to display "ignored" records when the controller gathers the records and renders them. When unchecked, "ignored" records are filtered out of view. When checked, "Ignored" records are then included into the view.

Comment: Okay you do know that the controller runs before the view displays right?  The controller creates the view and displays it (either through the render command or the implicit render command in the controller method). It is only after a submit that any of the params show up in the controller execution?

Comment: Ah ok so then I need to specify the default in the controller after all. Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem I figured it was a misunderstanding. Just remember Browser Looks at Path -> Rails loads controller -> Rails loads controller method. -> Method sets which view to render loads and interprets view and sends html back to browser

And if this helped please vote select the answer.